# Uninstalling eclipse plugin error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uninstallation

When I try to uninstall my eclipse plugin the following error occurs:

```
An error occurred while uninstalling 
enter code heresession context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]de.test.package.one 0.1.0.201008170949 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
 Error while loading manipulator.
Caused by: Application failed,
```

Most topics refer to the eclipse.ini file, which I modified but that didn't solve the problem. The eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520
```

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: did you try with a modified `eclipse.ini` like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse ?

Comment: thanks for that advice but yeah, I already tried to modify the things described in that thread. 
But I finally solved the problem. I'm installing/uninstalling the plugin on an eclipse rcp, which has its own .ini file. The problem was, that on start an eclipse.ini file is created. After removing this file I can install/uninstall the plugin. 

Next problem is, that on every update of a plugin a new eclipse.ini file is created and must be removed. Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to know that I solved the: "An error occurred while uninstalling" problem. by:

1.) rename the eclipse.ini file to a non ini name (eclipse.xxx)
2.) start eclipse
3.) Install the software/plugin
4.) restore the ini file.

I wonder why Eclipse can start in the first place but it works.
The renaming of the executable did NOT work for me.

Comment: This does not work for me at all. It results in "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library."